# RadioButton not checked on RadioGroup button click in Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, radio-button

Sometimes my `RadioGroup` buttons are not checked while selecting. I am using `Xamarin.Android` and I have about 15 `RadioButtons` in `RadioGroup`. What is strange is that the focus is always set on the RadioButton clicked, but *sometimes* the same `RadioButton` is not set as Checked after click. Here is the sample code I currently use:

```
radioGroup.CheckedChange += delegate
{
    var radioButton = FindViewById<RadioButton>(radioGroup.CheckedRadioButtonId);
    radioButton.Focusable = true;
    radioButton.FocusableInTouchMode = true;
    radioButton.RequestFocus();
    radioButton.Checked = true;
};
```

What can I do to mark each RadioButton as Checked everytime I select it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It should be set Checked as soon as you click it. Don't set those properties inside the handler

Comment: I made it this way because I wanted the selected `RadioButton` to gain focus and to be set as Checked at the same time. What do you suggest for an improvement in this case?

Comment: when you click on button it will be set as Checked and get focus. Remove everything you have in your handler

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried to remove everything from handler, but still without success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is strange is that the focus is always set on the RadioButton clicked, but sometimes the same RadioButton is not set as Checked after click.

Because GetFocus always comes first when you click on the RadioButton, thus the `CheckedChange` event never got triggered when you click on the `RadioButton` for the first time.

So the correct way to do that is to register the `focusChange` event for every `RadioButton` and set the radio button to checked in the `focusChange` event handler:

```
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    RadioGroup radioGroup;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);
        radioGroup = FindViewById<RadioGroup>(Resource.Id.mGroup);

        //register focus change event for every sub radio button.
        for (int i = 0; i < radioGroup.ChildCount; i++)
        {
            var child=radioGroup.GetChildAt(i);
            if (child is RadioButton)
            {
                ((RadioButton)child).FocusChange += RadioButton_FocusChange;
            }
        }
    }


    private void RadioButton_FocusChange(object sender, Android.Views.View.FocusChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        //check if the radio button is the button that getting focus
        if (e.HasFocus){
            ((RadioButton)sender).Checked = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, method RadioButton_FocusChange() never gets called on `RadioGroup` button click.

Comment: can you share your project? This is really not complicated thing and works everywhere. As @Elvis said you should register for button events, not group events

Comment: @mrisek you can find my complete demo project [here](https://github.com/elvisxia/RadioButtonDemo). Please have a try.

Comment: Thanks for help, other methods were in conflict with `focusChange`.